# Azure website not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, web, azure-web-app-service

I have hosted one asp.net application with Sql server DB on Azure. It works fine usually but some times it stops responding or becomes very slow. This is not on any event like release, etc but happens very abruptly. After some time (15-20 mins) it again starts responding normally. At the same time, Azure management portal too fails to restart the web site during that time or make any operation.

Wanted to know if there is anything related to application or its been happening to all Azure sites?

Comment: not noticed anything in general, but then again there are so many datacentres. tbh this is quite vague. Are there any process running at the times of the slowdowns? What does the event viewer saying? Is logging detecting anything?  What times are this occurring at? Are the slowdowns occurring at regular intervals (e.g hours apart, or days?) How long has this being going on for? What are users doing when the slowdowns occur? Could a user be doing something which is causing an intensive, long-running process to occur?

Comment: Also, could it be a DOS/DDOS attack?

Comment: Nope, never noticed that with our sites. Must be something application related. Try creating a tiny web-site resembling your application and check if this happens to the sub-set of functionality

Comment: Re-created the same and it was down at the same time. I would understand this as a application problem only if I am able to find reason behind slowness of Azure Dashboard at the same time and errors I got from dashboard

Comment: Can you elaborate on the portal not able to stop/restart your site? Do you get any error? Would you be able to provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Websites in Free or Shared hosting plans have limits that are imposed and your site/processes will be suspended for the remainder of the current quota interval if it has exceeded the quotas -- I believe CPU and memory usage quotas are hourly, others may vary.  This post explains in more detail:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/08/02/windows-azure-web-sites-dashboard-management-page.aspx

Depending on your application, you may be hitting your quota on CPU or memory and that could be stopping your site temporarily.  I recently upgraded one of my sites from Shared to Basic because I began hitting quota restrictions.